# Contact class search async

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

In my application i use  `AddressChooserTask` to get a contact details

```
        AddressChooserTask m_AddressChooserTask = new AddressChooserTask();
        m_AddressChooserTask.Completed += new EventHandler<AddressResult>(OnAddressChooserTaskCampleted);
        m_AddressChooserTask.Show();
```

but every time i have an error in my eventhandler

```
        void OnAddressChooserTaskCampleted(object sender, AddressResult e)
    {
        

        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        {
            m_ContactRec.m_Name = e.DisplayName.ToString(); 
        }

        if (m_ContactRec.m_Name != null)
        {
            Contacts m_contacts = new Contacts();
            m_contacts.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<ContactsSearchEventArgs>(OnContactsSearchCompleted);               
            m_contacts.SearchAsync(m_ContactRec.m_Name, FilterKind.DisplayName, null);
             
        }

    }
```

[image]

the debugger is  stoping here `m_contacts.SearchAsync`.i am little bit confused, this event cleary is in the UI thread, can you tell me what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added

```
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_CONTACTS"/>
```

to WMAppManifest.xml?